# Do modern USB external disks need parking or "safe removal"? What is the recommended way to turn them off?

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-storage, external-drive, portable-harddrive

I am trying to turn the off when I do not use it, as Seagate 3.5-inch USB drives never seem to lower the spinning speed even after I have not accessed the drive for hours.

I would like to use the "Safely Remove" option of Windows, but I cannot use that for a reason. The external drive has no power button on it. Now, it isn't good just to physically unplug the DC adaptor of the drive, is it? Or does the drive intelligently detect the power cut-off and proceeds the necessary steps to power down the drive safely?

What is the recommended way to turn off a USB external disk?

Comment: Safe removal does not really park anything but merely flush the cache in the system memory ("dirty page") and the cache in the disk itself. Normally the drive should spin down after sometime it is "safely removed" since the filesystem is not mounted anymore (so there should be no more typical access), but it could be drive/enclosure-specific I guess.

Comment: In addition to what @TomYan said, programs that refuse to release references to files open on the drive (called "file handles" in windows) can prevent the "safe removal" from happening. I myself know when a drive is safe to remove and don't usually use the windows safe removal mechanism for this but I AM TAKING MY CHANCES AT POSSIBLE CORRUPTION.  They are my dice to roll.. and I might eventually pay for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows is assumed since you mentioned Windows. Below, OS means Windows, and Windows is the OS.

Answers to your questions:

> Do modern USB external disks need parking or "safe removal"?

Generally speaking, from a Windows perspective, Yes, removal of any drive requires safe removal to ensure no outstanding (i.e., cached) file system information remains unwritten, and to ensure no applications using the drive are interrupted while performing I/O or holding a file open. These two items just mentioned are really the same thing.

A hard drive is an electromechanical device with motors and semiconductors and firmware representing logic around managing things from the drive's perspective (not the OS's perspective).

An operating system supports file systems which, generally speaking, manage the logical structure used on the physical disk. The operating system indirectly interacts with the drive's firmware via established protocols (not critical for this discussion). The operating system's safe removal feature will ensure it issues all necessary commands to flush any pending file system data to the drive and to inform the drive of its logical disconnection.

Given all of this, think of Windows "Safe Removal" as merely (but importantly) an OS management operation where the OS (Windows) works to reach a point where it is logically finished with the drive such that there is no outstanding data yet to be written, that there are no apps using the drive.

Once Windows tells you removal is successful, you know Windows has reached that logical state, where you can be assured the drive has received any remaining file system updates/changes, and that no applications are using the drive.

Keep in mind, that logical state has no bearing on where the physical drive is in its endeavors. While the drive may be ready for power off, depending on the drive, that may be a bad assumption (more on this below).

> What is the recommended way to turn them off? ... What is the recommended way to turn off a USB external disk?

Follow the drive manufacturer's instructions, which most always include first successfully completing Windows Safe Removal, followed by removal cable/power if applicable. However, read the instructions for your drive and version of Windows as this is a general answer and there is no guarantee all drives have the same steps.

I have never seen an external USB drive manufacturer not recommend Windows Safe Removal first.

I will add, though, that I personally recommend adding the following to the manufacturer's steps:

1. Follow manufacturer steps which usually entail Windows Safe Removal steps.
2. After Safe Removal, wait some number of seconds before removing cables and power. I tend to use a "feel for the spin down" approach: I put my hand on the drive and wait to feel the vibration of spinning subside and then remove the cables.

Why do I add step 2, feeling the spin down? I have been burned before for reasons that could have been related to removing the power from the drive too quickly after safe removal, and since that time I have adopted adding the steps #2 above, feeling for the spin down. Even if a drive guarantees this precaution is not  required, I still do it... costs little so no harm/foul.. and probably safer.

> Now, it isn't good just to physically unplug the DC adaptor of the drive, is it?

No, it is never a good idea to remove power without first performing the steps for removal outlined in the manufacturer user's guide, which inevitably includes Windows Safe Removal first. As mentioned, Windows Safe Removal helps to ensure a logical disconnection of the OS which causes any file system flushing, ensuring no outstanding app's using the drive, and so forth. After all that, if I wish to disconnect ASAP, I put my hand on the drive to "feel for the spin down" and once I feel the vibration subside, I then remove the drive physically.

> Or does the drive intelligently detect the power cut-off and proceeds the necessary steps to power down the drive safely?

Unless the drive is clearly documented to support such, then No, do not assume that, and follow the manufacturer's recommended states, possibly adding the low-cost no harm/foul "feel for the spin down" step, if applicable.

Even if I were to have a drive which said it had a capacitor or some sort of minimal battery to drive shutdown on abrupt power removal, I would never rely on such alone and I would still use safe removal and feeling for the spin down. It costs little and your data is your data so it makes little sense to risk being fast and loose and not following the user guide, if not adding good extra precautionary steps.

> I would like to use the "Safely Remove" option of Windows, but I cannot use that for a reason.

Generally, given most any external drive's instructions for removal, you cannot avoid or skip Safe Removal and accomplish a good safe removal. You say "for a reason" ... if it is not top secret, you should probably say what your reason is for not performing the main step most any external USB drive manufacturer would list as part of appropriate removal. I mean, when you state that, you are effectively saying, "I do not wish to follow the drive manufacturer's steps for removing the drive, so how I can properly remove the drive?" It's contradictory.

Let me take a guess: If you wish to automate removal without user intervention, then you can write a program or script to safely remove. There may be some out there, but regardless, if it is done properly, it will not be guaranteed to remove the drive if something is holding on to use of the drive. You might then be able to poll Windows with such a script until removal succeeds, for example. But this guess as to why you cannot follow common steps seems out of scope from your core question which I've answered above. The answer provided means you cannot avoid safe removal...

Any removal or power off of a drive without safe removal *is not safe,* period, unless you gain guarantees of such by both Windows and the drive manufacturer, and I've never heard of such with any external USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can [set an external drive to avoid caching](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/turn-disk-write-caching-on-off), which allows the USB plug to be unplugged as long as the PC is not *actively* writing to the drive:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type *diskm*, and select *diskmgmt.msc*.
- Right-click on Disk*n* a the lower-left denoting the removable HDD, and select *Properties*.
- Open the *Policies* tab and select *Quick removal (default)* (likely already set).

Second, for extra assurance that the disk has had time to spin down, you can use Windows built-in *Safely Remove hardware* icon, or a third-party programs such as [HotSwap](http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm) or [USB Safely Remove](https://safelyremove.com/index.htm). My experience has been that these third-party applications are more reliable than Windows USB handling.

You do *not* need a power button on the external USB drive. Once the disk is safely ejected, simply unplug it from USB (and power source, if there is one).

Comment: Changes to Windows have made having to eject removable storage drives a thing of the past.  At least for flash storage devices.  A mechanical drive is a different story, but if you are not accessing files, the drive should be safe to eject. Quick removal is enabled by default and is the change I speak of by the way.